how to make a logger not using the global turbo filter in logback
I am trying to add a new logger into logback configuration. But some log messages has been filtered by the global turbo filter. Is there any way to avoid my newly added logger using the global turbo filter?
only 1 logger won't be filtered by global turbo filter, other loggers should use that turbo filter like before

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
